# Strange message 'Editor placeholder in source file' when using closure in Swift

Tags: swift

I have created an method with an closure that is used to fetch data by an AJax request, parse it and convert it to an struct:

```
static func getAllByCategory(category : String, completion : @escaping ([MenuItem]) -> Void) -> Void {
```

The category is needed to define from which category the menu items needs to be fetched.

The implementation is according Swift ok. But when i tried to call this method, Swift gives an strange error: `'Editor placeholder in source file'` when adding the category in this call:

```
MenuData.getAllByCategory(category: self.selectedCategory) { (menuItem) in

}
```

In the documentation Swift gives an example that looks exactly the same. What did i do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: clean , rerun this is ok or you may attach all context

Answer (score 0):

I did something stupid. Compiler gives error on an automatic piece called `code`. Error popup shows up on parameter but is caused in content. Problem solved.